# how to mount a partition inside a partition

Tags: partition-table

On my linux box I have a block device (/dev/sda5) that has been partitioned inside by a virtual machine. So, when I look inside with fdisk /dev/sda5, I see:

sda5p1
sda5p2

and so on. Is it possible to mount them on my host system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS?
My XP workstation doesn't have a /dev/sda5. My OpenBSD box neither and so are the AIX servers I'm working on...

Comment: It's definitely a *nix. probably linux that's the first extended partition on the first drive. so if you aren't using that many partitions on you *nix systems you wouldn't have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `kpartx` to generate device mapper nodes for each, then mount them individually.